# How do i find bits in virtual and physical address?

Tags: computer-architecture, virtual-memory

The question is:

```
Consider a virtual address space of 256 pages with page size of 4KB, mapped onto a physical memory of 128 frames. 
How many total bits are required in the virtual address? 
How many total bits are required in the physical address?
```

I can't figure out how to number of frames is used with the number of pages to find the bits required.

Can someone explain the steps required to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you're studying for the same finals as me :).

The bits for the virtual address can be calculated as $$\log_2( page size\ *\ number\  of\  pages )$$

For the physical the computation is, essentially the same $$\log_2( page size\ *\ number\  of\  frames )$$

In this case, 20 and 19 respectively.